# How does one round a floating point number to a specified number of digits?

Tags: rust

How does one round a f64 floating point number in Rust to a specified number of digits?

Answer (score 176, accepted):

If you want this just for display purposes, use the [formatting syntax built into `println!()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/fmt/). For example, to print a number rounded to 2 decimal places use the `{:.2}` format specifier:

```
fn main() {
    let x = 12.34567;
    println!("{:.2}", x);
}
```

If you want to put the rounded number in a string, use the [`format!()` macro](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.format.html).

If you want to round a number and get the result back as another number, then multiply the number by the given power of 10, call [`round`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.f64.html#method.round), and divide by the same power, e.g. to round to 2 decimal places, use 10<sup>2</sup> = 100.

```
fn main() {
    let x = 12.34567_f64;
    let y = (x * 100.0).round() / 100.0;

    println!("{:.5} {:.5}", x, y);
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=b94d0644ccc62a008ad87110b66da5d9&version=stable)

This prints `12.34567 12.35000`.

If the number of decimal places isn't known at compile time, one could use [`powi`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.f64.html#method.powi) to efficiently compute the relevant power.

Note that this will breakdown for very large numbers; specifically, numbers larger than `std::f64::MAX / power` (where `power` is the power of ten, e.g. 100 in the example above) will become infinity in the multiplication, and remain infinity after. However, `f64` cannot represent any fractional places for numbers larger than 2<sup>53</sup> (i.e. they're always integers), so one can special case such large numbers to just return themselves.

Comment: I wonder why there is no parameter for that in `.round()` - I guess because rust does not have defaults/overloaded functions?

Comment: Okay, well, what are we supposed to do if we aren't trying to print it?

Comment: @JeffDavenport either `format!` if you want a string, or multiply/round/divide as used to compute `y` in the second code block (the `println!`s in that example are just to show that the rounding worked).

Comment: Your `(x * 100.0).round() / 100.0` method not only breaks down for very large numbers. It is for example also incorrect for `let x: f64 = 0.01499999999999999944488848768742172978818416595458984375`, which is exactly representable by `f64`, should round to `0.01` but rounds to `0.02` instead.

Comment: `fmt` doesn't really "round", it's unreliable as [this example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015&gist=cc4de26f3dbac28daadd3b0160fdf3a5) illustrates. Sometimes it truncates, sometimes it rounds. It's quite obvious for a value like 0.25, which is 0.01 in binary and thus codes well in IEEE-754. Yet `{:.1}` yields the erroneous "0.2" instead of "0.3"...

Comment: `round` is only marginally better, see [this example comparing both](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=029e03c3f6302921574b62ab25c64ea3).

Comment: I think it would be good to emphasize in the second snippit that `y` still isn't *exactly* 12.35 -- perhaps also show `{y:.20}` so it displays as `12.34999999999999964473` to demonstrate that getting 12.35 in the output is still depending on cosmetic rounding, and that the value is the closest representable value to 12.35, but not 12.35 itself.

Answer (score 55):

To add to @huon's great answer, if you want to round a floating point number for display purposes, *but you don't know the precision at compile time,* you can use the precision formatting syntax as follows:

```
fn main() {
    let precision = 3;
    let x = 12.34567;
    println!("{:.1$}", x, precision); // prints 12.346 and works with `format!` as well
}
```

The documentation of [std::fmt](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/fmt/index.html#precision) has more examples on the syntax.

Answer (score 5):

Example round function with decimal count as a parameter:

```rust
fn round(x: f32, decimals: u32) -> f32 {
    let y = 10i32.pow(decimals) as f32;
    (x * y).round() / y
}
```

Comment: `assert_eq!(round(4.365, 2), 4.37);` fails

Answer (score 5):

In some applications, e.g. science, it makes more sense to round to significant digits rather than digits after the decimal. This is an implementation along with test code and documentation:

````
fn main() {
  println!("1230000.0 {} {}", 1230000.0, precision_f64(1230000.0, 2));
  println!("123000.0 {} {}", 123000.0, precision_f64(123000.0, 2));
  println!("12300.0 {} {}", 12300.0, precision_f64(12300.0, 2));
  println!("1230.0 {} {}", 1230.0, precision_f64(1230.0, 2));
  println!("123.00 {} {}", 123.00, precision_f64(123.00, 2));
  println!("12.300 {} {}", 12.300, precision_f64(12.300, 2));
  println!("1.2300 {} {}", 1.2300, precision_f64(1.2300, 2));
  println!(".12300 {} {}", 0.12300, precision_f64(0.12300, 2));
  println!(".01230 {} {}", 0.01230, precision_f64(0.01230, 2));
  println!(".00123 {} {}", 0.00123, precision_f64(0.00123, 2));
  println!("1.0000 {} {}", 1.00000, precision_f64(1.00000, 2));
}

/// Round to significant digits (rather than digits after the decimal).
///
/// Not implemented for `f32`, because such an implementation showed precision
/// glitches (e.g. `precision_f32(12300.0, 2) == 11999.999`), so for `f32`
/// floats, convert to `f64` for this function and back as needed.
///
/// Examples:
/// ```
///   precision_f64(1.2300, 2)                      // 1.2<f64>
///   precision_f64(1.2300_f64, 2)                  // 1.2<f64>
///   precision_f64(1.2300_f32 as f64, 2)           // 1.2<f64>
///   precision_f64(1.2300_f32 as f64, 2) as f32    // 1.2<f32>
/// ```
fn precision_f64(x: f64, decimals: u32) -> f64 {
  if x == 0. || decimals == 0 {
    0.
  } else {
    let shift = decimals as i32 - x.abs().log10().ceil() as i32;
    let shift_factor = 10_f64.powi(shift);

    (x * shift_factor).round() / shift_factor
  }
}
````

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example which builds on the `format!` macro, as explained by @huon:

```
fn more_info(name: &str, height: f32) -> String {
    let response = format!("My name is {name}, and I'm {height:.2} meters tall");
    response
}

fn less_info(name: &str, height: f32) -> String {
    let response = format!("My name is {name}, and I'm {height:.1} meters tall");
    response
}

#[test]
fn test_more_info() {
    let data = &[
        (
            "Bob",
            1.586,
            "My name is Bob, and I'm 1.59 meters tall",
            "round up and truncate to two decimals",
        ),
        (
            "Robert",
            1.7824,
            "My name is Robert, and I'm 1.78 meters tall",
            "no change",
        ),
    ];

    for (person, height, message, description) in data {
        assert_eq!(more_info(*person, *height), *message, "{}", description)
    }
}

#[test]
fn test_less_info() {
    let data = &[
        (
            "John",
            1.46,
            "My name is John, and I'm 1.5 meters tall",
            "no change",
        ),
        (
            "Jane",
            1.64,
            "My name is Jane, and I'm 1.6 meters tall",
            "round up and truncate to one decimal",
        ),
    ];

    for (person, height, message, description) in data {
        assert_eq!(less_info(*person, *height), *message, "{}", description)
    }
}
```