# How to format a float without trailing zeros in Rust?

Tags: rust

I'm formatting `f64` like this:

```
format!("{:.8}", x)
```

This returns strings like this:

```
110.00000000
601.47000000
4.50000000
```

I'm looking to remove all the extra zeros at the end of each so that the output is this:

```
110
601.47
4.5
```

I'm hoping to do this without any external crates or libraries (not a big deal if it has to happen though). Is there something built-in to Rust that can accomplish this? Or will I have to write a custom function to do so?

Edit:

I should add that I can't simple do `format("{}", x)` because that will return strings like this:

```
40.019999999999996
1192.6499999999999
2733.9599999999996
```

Is there a way around that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This currently solves [the issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50361151/how-to-deal-with-inexact-floating-point-arithmetic-results-in-rust) for me:

```rust
let y = (x * 100_000_000.0).round() / 100_000_000.0;
format!("{}", y);
```

I will keep an eye out for any better solutions. Thank you!

Answer (score -2):

You can just do

```rust
format!("{}", x)
```

The `{:.8}` requires 8 places of precision, and thus, prints out extra zeros to that precision.

Comment: Not quite what I'm looking for, as that returns strings like this:56.74000000000001
8.940000000000001
89.63000000000001
103.42999999999998

Comment: That just looks like a natural fact of floating point imprecision, you'd just have to choose when you're close enough for your purposes to round.

Comment: Your caveat doesn't answer the OP's question it just rationalizes why it's the way it is