# How to round a number up or down in Rust?

Tags: rust, rounding

How to floor or ceil numbers?  I tried to use the `round` crate but either it doesn't work or I'm using it wrong.

```rust
use round::round_down;

fn main() {
  println!("{}", round_down(5.5f64, 0));  
}
```

This prints `5.5` but should print `5`.

My `Cargo.toml` file contains this:

```
[dependencies]
round = "0.1.0"
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does one round a floating point number to a specified number of digits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28655362/how-does-one-round-a-floating-point-number-to-a-specified-number-of-digits)

Comment: The package doesn't claim to handle rounding to zero digits (it says 1 to 10). Why not [use `math::round::floor`](https://docs.rs/libmath/0.1.4/math/round/fn.floor.html)?

Comment: @dorukerenaktas: That handles regular rounding, not floor rounding, right?

Comment: follow documentation of Primitive Type f64: https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.f64.html

Answer (score 48, accepted):

As stated in the comments you can use: [floor](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.f32.html#method.floor) and [ceil](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.f32.html#method.ceil)

```rust
fn main() {
    let num_32 = 3.14159_f32;

    println!("{}", num_32.floor()); // Output: 3
    println!("{}", num_32.ceil()); // Output: 4


    let num_64 = 3.14159_f64;

    println!("{}", num_64.floor()); // Output: 3
    println!("{}", num_64.ceil()); // Output: 4
}
```

Comment: Even with the `math = "0.1.0"` dependency I get `unresolved import 'math::round'`: `no 'round' in the root`.

Comment: Dependency name is libmath, and version is 0.2.1.

Comment: I don't understand, why this crate exists. [floor](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.f32.html#method.floor) and [ceil](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.f32.html#method.ceil) are provided by the language already.

Comment: @IInspectable the provided functions are for `f32`, in the question `f64` is asked as i understand correctly.

Comment: The exact same functions are of course available for f64

Comment: @JussiKukkonen you are right. I checked it now. It's my fault that i did not searched it correctly in the docs.

Answer (score 5):

if you have only integers, you may use this trick:

```
// down
a / b

// up
a / b + (a % b).signum()
```

Example:

```
let a: i32 = 5;
let b: i32 = 2;

// down
println!("floor = {}" , a / b);

// up
println!("ceil = {}" , a / b + (a % b).signum());
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=7384591ab60b91929bdd4ff160056337)

Comment: This doesn't work for negative numbers. `-2/4` return `0` which is `ceil` and not `-1` which is floor

Answer (score 3):

```rust
fn main() {
  let mut num = 5.5_f64;
  num = num.floor();
  print!("{}", num); // 5
}
```

Comment: `i32` doesn't have a `floor()` method because you can't round an integer.

Comment: Rounding an int makes sense if you want to round to the nearest 1000 (say)