# How to serialize a struct containing f32 using serde_json?

Tags: json, rust, serde, reqwest, serde-json

Relatively new to Rust. I am trying to make an API call which requires the JSON body to be serialized.

The JSON body contains an order_amount key with value which can only take values having INR format 100.36, i.e. Rupees 100 and paise 36. Some more examples 10.48, 3.20, 1.09.

The problem I'm facing is that after serialization with json!() from serde_json, the floating point value becomes something like 100.359765464332.

The API subsequently fails because it expects the order_amount to have only two decimal places.

Here is the code that I have:

The imports

```
use lambda_runtime::{handler_fn, Context, Error};
use reqwest::header::ACCEPT;
use reqwest::{Response, StatusCode};
use serde_json::json;
use std::env;

#[macro_use]
extern crate serde_derive;
```

The struct that I'm serializing

```
#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Clone, Debug)]
struct OrderCreationEvent {
    order_amount: f32,
    customer_details: ...,
    order_meta: ...,
}
```

Eg. The order_amount here has a value of 15.38

```
async fn so_my_function(
    e: OrderCreationEvent,
    _c: Context,
) -> std::result::Result<CustomOutput, Error> {
let resp: Response = client
        .post(url)
        .json::<serde_json::Value>(&json!(e))
        .send()
        .await?;
```

After json!(), the amount is being serialized to 15.379345234542. I require 15.38

I read a few articles about writing a custom serializer for f32 which can truncate to 2 decimals, but my proficiency is limited in Rust.

So, I found this code and have been tinkering at it with no luck:

```
fn order_amount_serializer<S>(x: &f32, s: S) -> Result<S::Ok, S::Error>
where
    S: Serializer,
{
    s.serialize_f32(*x)
    // Ok(f32::trunc(x * 100.0) / 100.0)
}
```

Whether or not the custom serializer is the right approach or solution to the problem, I would still like to learn how to write one, so feel free to enlighten me there too.
Cheers! :)

Comment: General advice. It is bad idea to store money as floats because `.1 + .2 != .3`  problem. Either use default precision of 2 and store value as number of paise `u32`, or create a Money struct that has value and precision. https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/money.html

Comment: What do you mean by "tinkering it with no luck"? Does it not compile? Have you tried the "obvious" `s.serialize_f32(f32::trunc(*x * 100.0) / 100.0)`?

Comment: @user4815162342 It compiles. The solution you've given me compiles too. 
Here's a playground: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=bcd23f9a2af8212259946619cf644828

Hope it explains what's happening.

Comment: @YuryTarabanko I'm not storing the value. I need to serialize and pass it on to an API.

Comment: I think I see what's the problem. Does this work: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=f44ec769a13d7a21c19d67d38faae1b9

Comment: @user4815162342 it definitely works. I don't understand why it works though. Would be glad if you could explain what you've done there.

Comment: It's a floating-point issue of widening f32->f64. I've written an answer that explains it in some detail.

Comment: @snipedown21 You do store it in memory :) But whatever.

Comment: Never, ever (ever!) store a monetary value (e.g. a price, a balance) as a floating point number. The result *will* be wrong, and it will be wrong in the most horrifying way. Just full-precision integers!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**TL;DR** it's a floating-point issue coming from `serde_json` widening `f32` to `f64`. You can reproduce it with code as simple as `println!("{}", 77.63_f32 as f64)`. To fix it, you need to convert to `f64`, then round, and serialize it as `f64`:

```
s.serialize_f64((*n as f64 * 100.0).trunc() / 100.0)
```

---

#### Detailed explanation

The problem in the code lies in a different place than where you think it is - it has to do with floating-point precision and not with serde. When you write something like:

```
let lat = 77.63_f32;
```

...you instruct the compiler to convert the fraction 7763/100 into `f32`. But that number cannot be exactly represented by an `f32` because `f32` (like all binary floating-point types) uses binary fractions, i.e. rationals whose denominators are powers of two within some size limits. Given those constraints, 7763/100 gets approximated as 10175119/2**17.<sup>1</sup> If you try to print that `f32` value, you'll [get the expected 77.63](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=0131125c3c22ed1a15be87170ffe9776) output because `println!()` knows it's printing an `f32` where all digits after the 7th one are side effect of approximation and to be discarded.

`serde_json` works differently - it serializes `f32` values by [converting them to `f64`](https://github.com/serde-rs/json/blob/9af851709f0455affa230788246b364bb98c449a/src/value/ser.rs#L133) because that is the precision used by JSON and JavaScript. The unfortunate consequence of that is that the 10175119/2**17 approximation of `77.63_f32` gets widened to `f64` without the context of the original desire to store 77.63. The `f64` simply stores the approximation (which it can accommodate exactly, without further loss of precision), and when you print the resulting `f64`, you [get](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=6eedcf18032eec65502fada28793e336) 77.62999725341797, that's what 10175119/2**17 looks like in decimal to 16 digits of precision.

This is why implementing a custom serialize as `s.serialize_f32(f32::trunc(*x * 100.0) / 100.0)` has no effect - you rounded an `f32` to two decimal digits (which is in your program a no-op because it was rounded to begin with), and then you passed it to `serialize_f32()`. `serialize_f32()` proceeds to widen the `f32` value to `f64` which makes the extra digits from the `f32` approximation visible - and you're back to where you started from with the implementation generated by serde.

The correct version must convert `f32` to `f64`, then get rid of the extra digits *in f64 type*, and then pass it to `serialize_f64()` for printing:

```
s.serialize_f64((*n as f64 * 100.0).trunc() / 100.0)
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=e44d6c634b14271bac1760b2cf7fe00e)

That works because: the number `77.63_f32` gets converted to the `f64` that corresponds to 10175119/2**17 (i.e. **not** `77.63_f64`, which would be approximated<sup>2</sup> to 682840701314007/2**43). This number then gets rounded to two digits **in f64**, and that rounding produces the closest approximation of 77.63 that `f64` is capable of. I.e. now we get the same 682840701314007/2**43 approximation we'd get by using `77.63_f64` in Rust source code. That's the number that serde will work with, and `serde_json` will format it as `77.63` in JSON output.

Side note: the above code uses `trunc()` following the attempt in the question, but maybe `round()` [as shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28656825/1600898) would be a more appropriate choice.

---

<sup>1</sup>
You can obtain this ratio with this Python one-liner:

```py
>>> numpy.float32("77.63").as_integer_ratio()
(10175119, 131072)
```

<sup>2</sup>
Also obtained using Python:

```py
>>> n = 10175119/131072
>>> rounded = round(n*100.0)/100.0
>>> rounded
77.63
>>> rounded.as_integer_ratio()
(682840701314007, 8796093022208)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need precise control about the formatting of your JSON messages `serde_json` provides the tools you need. Producing JSON goes through the [`serde_json::ser::Formatter`](https://docs.rs/serde_json/1.0.85/serde_json/ser/trait.Formatter.html) trait. You can write the `write_f32`/`write_f64` functions in a way, that they only produce two digits after the dot. You can take one of the already existing implementations and adapt them to your need.

Answer (score 0):

Example serializing `f16` rounded to three decimals.

```
use half::f16;
use serde::{Deserialize, Deserializer, Serialize, Serializer};
use serde_json;

fn f16ser3<S>(fv: &f16, se: S) -> Result<S::Ok, S::Error>
where
    S: Serializer,
{
    se.serialize_f64((fv.to_f64() * 1000.).round() / 1000.)
}

fn f16des3<'de, D>(des: D) -> Result<f16, D::Error>
where
    D: Deserializer<'de>,
{
    f64::deserialize(des).and_then(|fv| Ok(f16::from_f64(fv)))
}

#[derive(Clone, Debug, Deserialize, Serialize)]
struct Foo {
    #[serde(serialize_with = "f16ser3", deserialize_with = "f16des3")]
    bar: f16,
}

fn main() {
    let foo = Foo {
        bar: f16::from_f32(1.23),
    };
    let foo_s = serde_json::to_string(&foo).unwrap();
    println!("{}", foo_s);  // {"bar":1.23}
}
```

https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=4149756d2c9058f9d073f4a39a4ece9c